# Cannot edit JSON file after building for Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have built Unity project for Android build and it loads StreamingAssets during runtime. After build is completed, when I open the .apk through zip and change the JSON content, this is the error I get when I try installing the APK:

```
adb: failed to install FileName.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl447466466.tmp/base.apk: META-INF/CERT.SF indicates /data/app/vmdl447466466.tmp/base.apk is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2, but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify your app after you signed it. Changing the json content you invalidate signature scheme.